# Google App Engine launch RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'php'; supported runtimes are 'custom'

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, sdk

I am trying to deploy WordPress on Google App Engine and I followed [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting-a-wordpress-website-on-google-app-engine--cms-2213), but when I try to launch it with the launcher, the launch fails and I get the following errors in my log console:

```
2016-02-09 17:15:23 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=9080', '--admin_port=8001', u'C:\\appengine']"
INFO     2016-02-09 17:15:36,940 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-02-09 17:15:37,907 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55370
INFO     2016-02-09 17:15:37,907 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-02-09 17:15:37,907 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 824, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\dispatcher.py", line 193, in start
    _module, port = self._create_module(module_configuration, port)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\dispatcher.py", line 278, in _create_module
    threadsafe_override=threadsafe_override)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1155, in __init__
    super(AutoScalingModule, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 537, in __init__
    self._module_configuration)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 229, in _create_instance_factory
    sorted(repr(k) for k in runtime_factories.FACTORIES))))
RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'php'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java7', 'php55', 'python', 'python-compat', 'python27'.
2016-02-09 17:15:38 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I am quite confused, because I have followed all the steps and I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Try changing `runtime: php` to `runtime: php55` in `App.yaml`.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your error

> RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'php'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java7', 'php55', 'python', 'python-compat', 'python27'.

means that your `app.yaml` file isn't setup correctly. Right now Google App Engine only supports PHP 5.5, so you have to choose

```
runtime: php55
```

to run your app with PHP.

Comment: thank you wogsland, it worked just fine... but then i have hit another brick wall, i got my wordpress application running on my local machine, but when i try to deploy it live on the Google App Engine i get his error "Error establishing a database connection" ,    this is my connection part for my wp-config.php file          /** MySQL hostname */
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
  define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/hoasql-2016');
}else{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
}
  NOTE: hoasql-2016 is my instance ID. please help

Comment: @Norbert Generally on SO if you have another question you ask another question and mark your previous one solved by accepting an answer. That said, from your snippet I'm guessing you are setting you're database host on GAE when instead you need to be setting the socket.